# How to migrate contacts from Google Apps to Gmail account?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, migrate-data

I want to move the contacts from the Apps account. I have successfully exported them three times, once according to each of the formats provided by Google (Google CSV, "outlook-style" CSV and Vcards. I've looked in the files (using excel, [CSV File View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/csv_file_view.html) and [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) & they look fine - headers and data, etc.

When I attempt to import (I've tried all three  multiple times) all I get is ... nothing. The window closes, no messages and no imported contacts.

I then tried [TrueSwitch](http://www.trueswitch.com/), but couldn't seem to get it to accept my credentials (tried very carefully five times, but it keeps complaining about not being able to connect to my accounts). If TrueSwitch worked it would be the ideal tool, based on what it claims it does - but I can't get it to work.

Searching on the web has only turned up variations on "make sure the CSV file is formatted correctly - has the right headers, etc." It is correct, because gmail created it. And I've visually verified it.

If someone has an idea how I can get my contacts imported or migrated to the new gmail account, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I just did what you did and was successful. Please make sure to select `export` contacts in Google Apps and `import` in Gmail ;-)

Comment: Can you perhaps test with a smaller group of contacts, say three or four?

Comment: Jacob & Al - thanks for your input. See the answer below for how I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem in the import. There were about 3000 contact records. Around contact number 2900 I found there was an email field (that Google had exported) that contained eight (!) email addresses, separated by commas.

When I removed that record, Gmail imported the whole file OK. Before that, the entire file was not processed, even though the other records were OK.

I leave this information here to help any future person who runs into the weird case that Gmail can't read a file that Gmail itself generated.

It is not enough to verify the field names are correct. The data itself may be bad and even Gmail can be the culprit. It was hard, painstaking work to find this particular devil so deep in the file.

Perhaps a Gmail dev will read this & decide to add some sort of feedback to the Import Contacts tool - it's a shame that it currently fails completely silently.